# scrapy - Get final redirected URL

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to get the final redirected URL in scrapy. For example, if an anchor tag has a specific format:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/index.php" class="FOO_X_Y_Z" />
```

Then I need to get the URL that URL redirects to (if it does, if its 200 then OK). For example, I get the appropriate anchor tags like this:

```
def parse (self, response)  
    hxs     = HtmlXPathSelector (response);
    anchors = hxs.select("//a[@class='FOO_X_Y_Z']/@href");

    // Lets assume anchor contains the actual link (http://...)
    for anchor in anchors:
        final_url = get_final_url (anchor);   // << I would need something like this

        // Save final_url
```

So if I visited `http://www.example.com/index.php` and that would send me through 10 redirects and finally it would stop at `http://www.example.com/final.php` - this is what I would need `get_final_url()` to return.

I thought of hacking my way to a solution but am asking here to see if scrapy has one already provided?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Again, assuming `anchor` contains an actual URL, I went and accomplished it with **urllib2**:

```
def parse (self, response)  
    hxs     = HtmlXPathSelector (response);
    anchors = hxs.select("//a[@class='FOO_X_Y_Z']/@href");

    // Lets assume anchor contains the actual link (http://...)
    for anchor in anchors:
        final_url = urllib2.open(anchor, None, 1).geturl()

        // Save final_url
```

`urllib2.open()` returns a file-like object with two additional methods, one of them being `geturl()` which returns the final URL (after all redirects have been followed). Its not part of Scrapy, but it works.

Comment: In Python 3 you can achieve it like this                                                                                          
        `final_url = urllib.request.urlopen(anchor).geturl()`

Answer (score 1):

I use `response.headers` that will return a list of information. The new url value is next to the "Location" key.

```
In [1]: response.headers
Out[1]: 
{'Date': 'Thu, 09 Jun 2016 00:18:18 GMT',
 'Location': 'https:/www.protiviti.com/en-US/Pages/default.aspx',
 'Server': 'nginx/1.9.1',
 'X-Ms-Invokeapp': '1; RequireReadOnly'}
```

Comment: That was my first thought to check the headers, however I'm in a situation where the server is not updating the headers to reflect the final URL

Answer (score -4):

It's pretty simple:

```
print response.url #(inside parse() )
```

Comment: Actually, thats the URL of where the resource I just got is located. I need the final URL of the link in the href attribute. I wasn't clear enough I guess. Thank you anyway.